# Random walk increasing distance

Tags: random-walks

I'm wondering why if I increase the number of step in a set of simulation of a random walk on a grid the distance from the origin is higher.

If I can move on the grid in 4 directions, there are 0.5 chance of getting closer to origin and 0.5 of getting farther.

This is a simple javascript example (well, here maybe I made some other errors because the points ends always with a negative x and a positive y, or maybe I just cannot rely on javascript random function in this case)

```
var steps = 100; //number of steps for each simulation (initially)
var simulations = 100; //number of total simulation
var points = Array.from({length:simulations}, () => ({x:0,y:0})); // init the array of points from the origin

//the 4 possible moves
var moves = [{x:0,y:1},{x:1,y:0},{x:0,y:-1},{x:-1,y:0}];
//ranom util function
var random = (max) => parseInt(Math.random() * max)

for (var s=0;s < simulations;s++) {
    //note the steps are increasing: 100,200,300,...,1000
    for (var i=1;i <= steps * s;i++) {  
        let move = moves[random(4)];
        //console.log(move)
        points[s].x += move.x
        points[s].y += move.y
        //console.log(s, move)
    }
    console.log(`simulation n.${s} total steps: ${steps*s}`, points[s].x, points[s].y, `distance: ${Math.abs(points[s].x) + Math.abs(points[s].y)}` )

}
```

**EDIT**: thanks to @GASSA I fixed my code, but watching the results I'm still in doubt: **the distance actually is not increased** (see the graph below). Not sure what's the problem..

[image]

Comment: Also, note that the line `var moves = [{x:0,y:1},{x:0,y:1},{x:0,y:-1},{x:-1,y:0}];` is buggy: one of `{x:0,y:1}` should be `{x:1,y:0}` instead.

Comment: @Gassa thanks, please see my edit and the graph, it would be nice make this code works like a random walk should behaves :)

Comment: To edit: what makes you think the distance does not increase? As per @D.W.'s answer, the distance normally is on the order of sqrt(n). The square root of 10000 is 100, and a distance on the order of a hundred or two is what we seem to see on your graph, as far as scale and resolution permit.

Comment: @Gassa sorry I noticed I plot the data in the dumbest way possible, please see the new graph

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4):

It's easiest to understand with a one-dimensional random walk.  After $n$ steps, the typical value for the distance from the origin is proportional to $\sqrt{n}$.  Thus, the more steps you take, the greater the typical distance from the origin.  For an analysis and explanation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk.  The math is well-developed in many standard places, so I'm not going to repeat it here.

Answer (score 1):

A two-dimensional random walk is equivalent to two independent one-dimensional random walks running in parallel. To see this, rotate the plane 45 degrees. The possible steps are all four diagonals, and each one corresponds to both a step in the horizontal direction and a step in the vertical direction.

The horizontal displacement after $n$ steps is the sum of $n$ random $\pm 1$ steps. According to the central limit theorem, its distribution is roughly normal with mean zero and variance $n$. Consequently, the absolute horizontal displacement is of expected order $\sqrt{n}$. The same is true for the absolute vertical displacement, and so for the distance from the origin.